# Is there half an iteration of the QR algorithm?

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-dynamical-systems, fractional-iteration

Every real square matrix $M$ has a QR decomposition $M = QR$ where $Q^{-1}=Q^T$ and $R$ is an upper triangular matrix with non-negative reals on the diagonal. Call the function $f(QR)=RQ$ the *Francis function*. The Francis function is continuous over invertible matrices, and is well-behaved in a certain way over PSD matrices (see [my video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvTRlE0qBBp35rv11Wp3WCWSixUisJqY4); I'm not sure how to describe it formally). **Is there a functional square root of the Francis function over PSD matrices?** My visualisations suggest that there could be one.

Comment: Is your Francis function uniquely defined if $M$ is singular?

Comment: Does anyone know how to describe in formal terms how the "Francis function" is well-behaved over PSD matrices?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms The QR decomposition is only unique subject to the requirement that the diagonal entries of R be positive. This should be easy to fix in Matlab or Numpy, or whatever software you're using

Comment: @GottfriedHelms Make sure that the matrix R you get from your different algorithms has positive entries along its diagonal.

Comment: Uniqueness proof: $QR = Q'R'$ implies $Q^TQ' = R(R')^{-1}$. The LHS is orthogonal, and the RHS is upper triangular. By the orthogonality property, the inverse of the RHS is its transpose. But the inverse of an upper triangular matrix is upper triangular. Therefore the transpose of the RHS is upper triangular. Therefore the RHS is diagonal. A diagonal matrix which is orthogonal has $\pm 1$ along its diagonal. Therefore $R = R' \operatorname{diag}(\pm 1, \pm 1, \dotsc, \pm 1)$. Recall the claim about what $R$ is unique up to. From this, uniqueness of $Q$ is easy to show under the same conditions

Answer (score 3):

Look for the [Toda flow](https://doi.org/10.1137/0605020); that should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L_{n\times n}=L(t)$ being a real or complex matrix, with $t$ being a real number. You can define $$B(t)=L^*(t)_+-L(t)_-,$$ in which $L_+$ is the upper triangular part, and $L_-$ is the low triangular part of the matrix $L$, without the diagonal. It follows that $B^*=-B$.

Let us consider the function $U(t)$ as the solution to the initial value problem
$$\frac{d\,U}{dt}=BU,\qquad U(0)=I,$$ in wich
$I$ denotes the identity  $n\times n$ matrix.

This means that
$$\frac{d\,U^*U}{dt}=\left(\frac{d\,U}{dt}\right)^*U+U^*\frac{d\,U}{dt}=(BU)^*U+U^*BU=-U^*BU+U^*BU=0,$$ and follows that $U^*(t)U(t)=U^*(0)U(0)=I$, that is, $U(t)$ and $Q(t)=U^*(t)$ are bounded orthogonal matrix to each $t\in \mathbb{R}$.

It follows that the initial value problem
$$\frac{d\,L}{dt}=BL-LB,\qquad L(0)=L_0,$$ has a unique solution $$L(t)=Q^*(t)L_0Q(t).$$

**Lemma:** If $L_0=L_0^*$, then $L(t)$ converges to a diagonal matrix, containing each eigenvalues of $L_0$,  as $|t|\to \infty$.

Now, if you let $$B=B(t)=\left[G(L(t))^*\right]_+-G(L(t))_-,$$ to some  [analytical function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function#Real_versus_complex_analytic_functions) $G(z)$, to  $z$ in an open set of $\mathbb{C}$, containig the eigenvalues of $L_0$. It follows that $B^*=-B$, and that
$$M(t)=G(L(t))=U(t)G(L_0)U^*(t)$$ is the solution to the initial value problem $$ \frac{d\,M}{dt}=BM-MB,\qquad M(0)=G(L_0).$$

**Lemma:** If $L_0=L_0^*$ and $G(z)$ is real and one to one. Then  $e^{tG(L_0)}=Q(t)R(t)$, in which $R(t)$ is upper triangular with positive diagonal.

**Theorem:**    $e^{G(L(m))}$ is the m-th iteration  to the [$QR$  iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) to $e^{G(L_0)}$. In particular, if $L_0=\pm A^*A$, we can choose $G(z)=\ln(\pm z)$.

You can find details in [the paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2157017?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) "Nanda, T., Differential Equations and the QR Algorithm, SIAM Journal on Numerical Analysis
Vol. 22, No. 2, 310--321, 1985".

You can find related results searching for "(
\frac{dX}{dt} ,=, B(X)X-XB(X), \quad X(0),=, A,
) " and for "Toda Flow" on SearchOnMath.